# static variable changing value with no error displayed?

Tags: c, printf, string-literals, conversion-specifier

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=10;
    static int b=2;
    a = a+1;
    b = b-1;
    printf("%d \n",a);
    printf("%d \n",b);
    printf("%d \n","%d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
11
1
4210693
```

**My Question:**
b is a static variable, so how come its value changed in the second printf() function used? The third printf() function makes sense because it has given an error.

Comment: It changes value because you explicitly did so in the line `b = b-1;` - `static` does not mean immutable

Comment: The value may be changed due to *undefined behavior*, which allows anything to happen.

Comment: As @UnholySheep suggested, I think you're confusing `static int b=2;` with `const int b=2;`

Comment: You have a `printf` call where you provide 3 parameters for a format string that only contains 1 format specifier. If your compiler did not tell you about that mismatch, you need to increase warning level. For GCC you can do this with `-Wall -Wextra`. If your compiler did tell you about that, listen to your compiler!

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Gerhardh I'm using Codeblocks and I will look for a way to increase its warning level because it hasn't warned me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters in the beginning of the program you changed the static variable `b`

```
b = b-1;
```

the keyword `static` does not have the meaning as the keyword `const`.

On the other hand, in this call of `printf` there is evidently a typo

```
printf("%d \n","%d",a,b);
               ^^^^
```

In fact you are trying to output a pointer to the string literal `"%d"` as an integer.

That is the function has four arguments and only one conversion specifier in the first argument.

The compiler could issue a warning that there are redundant arguments in the call of `printf`.

You could write for example like :)

```
printf("%d \n" "%d",a,b);
```

In this case the output would be

```
11
1
```

Because the above call is equivalent to

```
printf("%d \n%d",a,b);
```

But it seems you mean

```
printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
```

So neither static variable is changed spontanno.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I removed "static" and kept the declaration as int b, then it would be the same as static int b. so what is the use of static variable if it's going to change the value anyway?

Comment: @user134613 A static variable declared in a function keeps its value between function calls. It has static storage duration opposite to other variables declared within the function that have automatic storage duration.

Comment: so if the static variable was declared inside a function then we can't change its value inside the function but we can do so outside the function?

Comment: @user134613 No you are wrong. A variable declared in a function is its local variable that is not visible outside the function where it is declared. But it keeps its value between calls of the function.

Comment: What do you exactly mean "between calls of the function" ?

Comment: @user134613 If you will run this program #include <stdio.h>

void f( void )
{
 static int x = 0;
 printf( "x = %d\n", x );
 ++x;
}

int main(void) 
{
 f();
 f();
 f();
 
 return 0;
}
 then the program output will be x = 0
x = 1
x = 2

Answer (score 2):

`printf` signature is

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

The first parameter is the format string and all the following parameters are the format specifiers (subsequences beginning with %).

```
printf("%d \n","%d",a,b);
```

The code above invokes *undefined behaviour* because the first format specifier `%d` is used to present decimal integer value while the parameter matching this specifier is `"%d`" which has type `const char *`.

You should change it to:

```
printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
```